# Gaussian-like integral on spherical hypersurface

Tags: real-analysis, surface-integrals, gaussian-integral

I am interested in the calculation of the following integral in $\mathbb R^N-1$:
\begin{equation}
I_A=\int_{||x||^2=R^2} \mathrm d \sigma \; e^{-\frac 12 x^T A x}
\end{equation}
where $A$ is postive definite. I tried to rewrite the surface of integration as a delta function
\begin{equation}
\delta(||x||^2-R^2) = \frac 1 {2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathrm d k\; e^{ik(||x||^2-R^2)}
\end{equation}
and to incorporate the above constraint in the precision matrix, by rescaling
\begin{equation}
A \rightarrow B(k)= A-2ik1_N
\end{equation}
where $1_N$ denotes the $N\times N$ identity matrix. I cannot however progress further with standard results on Gaussian integrals, given that $\Re(\det B(k))<0$ for large values of $k$. Is there another approach to solve $I_A$?